# how to validate empty fields in javascript and pass error message to alert bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, alert

I want to validate fields by using javascript and pass the error message to a bootstrap alert. How can I achieve this? Anyone can help? Here is my javascript function:

```
function validateValues() {
    var f = document.frm;

    if (f.UsrID.value == "") {
        alert('Please fill in User ID'); < --How to pass this error message to Bootstrap alert ?
            f.UsrID.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is where I want to display the error message

```
<div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <strong>Error message:</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use jQuery validator.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap alone can validate your forms without any addition scripts:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" data-error="Bruh, that email address is invalid" required>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="alert alert-danger fade in" id="putinhere">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <strong>Error message:</strong>
</div>

function validateValues() {
var f = document.frm,
    x = document.getElementById('putinhere');

if (f.UsrID.value=="") {
    x.children[2].innerHTML += ' Please fill in User ID.';
    f.UsrID.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

I put an ID on you div so I can get/reference it much easier. #EZ4rtz

Comment: Thank you for your solution but I'm sorry, it did not work for me. It does not validate the field at all. Instead, it proceeds to the next page. Unlike before, when i use javascript alert, it validates the field. Am I missing something here?

Comment: onsubmit = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }